# Can't make https working and use SSL certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I will tell you about my task: I need to pay my users, but I want to make it secure with SSL. I created self-signe certificate using [this](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) post.

I followed 1A instruction.

Also, installed these gems:

```
     gem 'rack-ssl'
     gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', '~>1.4.0', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
```

I have only one payment page, so I added in my controller:

```
    ssl_required :admin_page
```

On this page admin see unpayed payments and pays to users.

I read this article http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/
and followed instructions about how to use https protocol. I tried to add it into my application.rb and development.rb.

I have this line in my application.rb

```
      config.force_ssl = false
```

Should I delete it ?

Error from development log:

```
      Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected
```

How can I solve this and how I should use SSL certificate ?

Comment: are you using https to go that page ?

Comment: Yes. What you can suggest about that ?